# When I converted this .py program to an .exe file, I have problems with speech_recognition

Tags: python, tkinter, speech-recognition, pyinstaller

I'm creating a Voice-Assistant in python and tkinter, and I use pyinstaller to convert it to an executable file. The command line is:

```
pyinstaller -F -w main.py
```

This is my code:

```
import pyttsx3
from pyttsx3.drivers import sapi5
import speech_recognition as sr
import time
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime

engine = pyttsx3.init()
rate = engine.getProperty("rate")
engine.setProperty("rate", 175)
volume = engine.getProperty("volume")
engine.setProperty("volume", 0.75)
voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
engine.setProperty("voice", voices[2].id)

window = Tk()

var = StringVar()
var1 = StringVar()

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        window.title("Voice-Assistant")
        window.geometry("1280x720")
        window.resizable(False, False)
        window.iconbitmap(r"C:\Users\itsju\Documents\KarenDef\Projects\Karen10\IconofKaren.ico")

        karenW = Frame(window, bg="#3498db")
        karenW.place(relwidth=1, relheight=0.5, x=5, y=365)

        spokeW = Frame(window, bg="#1a5276")
        spokeW.place(relwidth=1, relheight=0.5, x=5)

        karenT = Label(karenW, bg="#3498db", fg="white", font=("Consolas", 16), textvariable=var1, wraplength=1230, justify="left")
        karenT.place(x=10, y=28)

        spokeT = Label(spokeW, bg="#1a5276", fg="white", font=("Consolas", 16), textvariable=var, wraplength=1230, justify="left")
        spokeT.place(x=10, y=28)

        karenL = Label(karenW, bg="#3498db", fg="white", font=("Calibri 11 bold underline"), text="Karen")
        karenL.pack()

        spokeL = Label(spokeW, bg="#1a5276", fg="light blue", font=("Calibri 11 bold underline"), text="You")
        spokeL.pack()

    def talk(self, audio):
        var1.set(audio)
        window.update()
        engine.say(audio)
        engine.runAndWait()

    def get_command(self):
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            var1.set("Listening...")
            window.update()
            audio = r.listen(source)
            spoke = ""
            try:
                var1.set("Recognizing...")
                window.update()
                spoke = r.recognize_google(audio, language='nl')
                var.set(spoke)
            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                var1.set("Couldn't get that!")
                window.update()
                time.sleep(0.25)
                var.set("")
            except sr.RequestError:
                var1.set("Check your internet connection!")
                window.update()
                time.sleep(0.5)
                var.set("")

            return spoke.lower()

a = App()

while True:
    spoke = get_command()
    if 'hello' in spoke:
        a.talk("Hello there!")
        break
```

So when this is converted, and I run the program, and it prints 'listening...' into my application. Then if I said something like 'Hello', my program should recognize it and say 'Hello there!' back. Though, it get's into one of the exceptions! If I convert my program with a terminal, command line: `pyinstaller -F main.py` without `-w` it works fine! But I don't want a terminal and my tkinter application opened.

Hope someone can help me with this weird problem! Thanks.

Comment: So u mean, there are no troubles when using a terminal? and there are errors when doing it on "windowed". What does the terminal show anyways, like anything is written or something

Comment: Yeah exactly! If I convert it without "windowed" and run it, nothing prints or shows up in the terminal, it just runs properly.

Comment: `pyinstaller -c -F main.py` what abt dis

Comment: I tried, but the terminal shows up! Then I tried ```pyinstaller -c -F -w main.py``` actually the same problem

Comment: -c is short for console,UDH to say -c AND -w. your issue is very weird.

Comment: Yeah I know it's weird! Thanks for your replies! Appreciate it!

Comment: but i want to help and my best guess is that, you are doing something with your exe (console ver) that you are not doing with your windowed exe

Comment: Okay, pyinstaller is using a different bootloader if converting without terminal, then converting with the terminal!

Comment: you are copying the exe to the project directory right?

Comment: Well after it's converted yes!

Comment: both the exe? the console and the windowed?

Comment: Yes that's right! I tried to put the both converted in the same folder with the .spec files, didn't work either

Comment: spec files are pretty useless wehn u make a onefile

Comment: Okay, but what can I try else?

Comment: im out of ideas, but maybe ask the Q once again.

Comment: Ok, I’ll try that then!

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to hide the console with the speech_recognition library:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow( ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(), 0 ) # Hide the console.
```